# BCP data export vs SSIS data export

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm in the middle of amending our data export process and was wondering whether to create an SSIS package in order to export the data, or whether BCP is the "preferred" method?

Comment: Just an idea, don't "accept" an answer so quickly. SSIS is most likely the way to go for what you're doing, but if you left the question open a bit longer you'd have gotten more opinions and ideas.

Comment: Doesn't SSIS use BCP for bulk-inserts under the covers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the plethora of tools and utilities available with SSIS, I would venture into creating a SSIS Package.

If you have the slightest idea that you will need to modify this to do any kind of data manipulation, SSIS would be a very good choice.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks.  I was still under the impression that BCP was the heavily favoured tool.

Comment: @Ardman: I'm sure it's heavily favored for what it's good for. It just isn't any good at manipulating the data as it's being transferred. Be sure to use the SQL Server 2008 version of SSIS, as it's _much_ faster in many important cases.

Comment: That's great information John.  I am using SSIS, but I certainly didn't know about the speed increase over 2005 (I guess).